# iOS app launch due to NSUserActivity. How do access that object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So testing some ios9 beta features as of now, but `NSUserActivity` class has been out for a while, which is used in handoff.

Basically this is it. When app launches doe to NSUserActivity, I can see that this the `launchOptions` has a key set.

```
    NSDictionary *userActivityKey = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey];
```

Basically the method never gets called.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
```

This makes sense as the app is just being opened due to the activity.
But what is puzzling me is this.

When I check the launchOptions, I am not able access the `NSUserActivity`. Apparently the OS creates that object for you??

Did any of you guys deal with this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I used a `UIAlertView` to get a description of the launchOptions when coming from an NSUserActivity:

```
NSDictionary *userActivityDictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert"
                                                    message:[userActivityDictionary description]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Apparently, this dictionary comes with a couple keys that I cannot seem to find documentation for:

```
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityIdentifierKey
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityTypeKey // there is documentation for this key
```

[image]

It seems the NSUserActivity object is inside this dictionary, but it may not be good from Apple's point of view (or it may break if Apple decides to change things), to try to access this object (e.g., possibly looping through the dictionary keys and looking for an NSUserActivity object).

**** Solution ****

EDIT: Here's some implementation on how to access the NSUserActivity object from launchOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *userActivityDictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey];
    if (userActivityDictionary) {
        [userActivityDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSUserActivity class]]) {
                    NSLog(@"found NSUserActivity object!");
                }
            }];
    }
}
```

Using this method, you don't need to know the value of the undocumented key, UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey.

If you're uncomfortable with the solution above, another method may be to catch the NSUserActivity object when your app enters this method,

```
- (BOOL)application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:
```

Then, set this user activity as a property of your AppDelegate for later retrieval.

Note: I was able to verify that the method above is called on a cold app launch while testing Core Spotlight (iOS 9 feature).

Comment: Yes exactly. I did the same. But you can't access the object after that. Even if I hard-code the key to UserActivityKey, it's not gonna help out.

Comment: How did you hard-code the key? We don't know what the backing string is for the constant, UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey =] -- unless I'm misunderstanding. Have you tried using the NSDictionary method: `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` and searching for `object == [NSUserActivity class]` ?

Comment: That is clean!! Yes enumerating is a clean way to go through this, and will be safe because of the check. Thank you @markckim Can you add this to the answer? I am sure it will help someone else.

Comment: done, hope it helps. i made an error in my comment above, you cannot use `==` here; you should use `isKindOfClass` for the comparison. this is reflected in the edit on the main post.

Comment: @markckim - Is it safe to access NSUserActivity object from launchOptions as Apple doesn't documented UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey? Do you know any apps has been submitted in appstore which access access NSUserActivity object from launchOptions ?

Comment: @Vijay you are not using any private API's to access the NSUserActivity object so my guess would be that Apple wouldn't even know that you are accessing this object this way. I wouldn't try using UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey though -- I would access the object using the dictionary enumeration method shown in my answer. However, I believe the safest way would be to have your app support the ability to use `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` to access this object.

Comment: Is it just me? Unfortunately @ernesto's answer below did not work, and it seems ridiculous that Apple would not provide a direct key to this value... but from the best of my research it's true!!!

I wonder if Apple goes through implementation scenarios before shipping their "features"...

Comment: This approach does work. You do not need to use an alert to find out what's in the launch options; there are ways to launch from a user activity and yet pause at breakpoints, so you can use Xcode to explore the launch options.

Answer (score 21):

You shouldn't be doing any of that. You should return `YES` from `-(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, then `-(BOOL)application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` will also be called. [Apple docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:):

> NO if the app cannot handle the URL resource or continue a user activity, otherwise return YES.

Comment: To the person who downvoted me: I've you think I am wrong, please explain!

Comment: I did not down vote, but I've tried this and unfortunately -(BOOL)application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler is still not called.

Comment: I've just verified that it works for me: https://github.com/herrernst/NSUserActivityExample
Create a new iOS single view swift Xcode project and replace AppDelegate and ViewController. Then, search for "example" in Spotlight.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. You do not get the NSUserActivity object in the launchOptions dictionary object. You need to return YES in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Watch out if you are using Facebook SDK and returning in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` `[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]` It will return **NO** and your `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` delegate will not be called!

Comment: This is the correct answer when dealing with Universal Links. The way I determine to return YES/true is if the launchOptions dictionary is non-nil. When you launch the app manually, the launchOptions dictionary is nil (so just `return launchOptions` at the end of `(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: @Lefteris I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: This is true in theory, but in practice there may be good reasons why the launch options need to be consulted and the event cannot be handled in `continueUserActivity`. And even the documentation invites the user to decide whether the app can continue the user activity, and how can we do that if we don't know how to fetch it? So this answer, basically saying that the original question should not have been asked, is just wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Swift answer:

```
// Handle universal link
    if let activityDic = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject],
              activity = activityDic["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {          
        handleActivity(activity)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

I am simply getting NSUserActivity like this:

**Objective C code**

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey])
{
    NSDictionary *activityDictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey];

    NSUserActivity *activity = [activityDictionary objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"];
}
```

Comment: i m always getting nil for launchOptions. how to set that.  i want to do something for  UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key..

Answer (score 0):

```
        if
            let userActivityDictionary = (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]),
            let userActivity = userActivityDictionary.values.first(where: { $0 is NSUserActivity }) as? NSUserActivity {

            //.....
        }
```

or

```
        if
            let userActivityDictionary = (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]),
            let userActivity = userActivityDictionary.values.map({ $0 as? NSUserActivity }).compactMap({$0}).first,
            self.deepLinkHandle(userActivity: userActivity) {

            //.....
        }
```